# Is there any way to get application logs in a running container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-container-instances

The only things I can find only give me logs at the Operating system level, like:

Container 'mycontainer' is in state 'Unknown'...
Container 'mycontainer' is in state 'Waiting'...
Container 'mycontainer' is in state 'Running'...

I have looked into installing a agent on the container but they only run on a handful of linux versions and the one I am using is not on that list. I am running the container in Azure container Instances. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have an application running in an `Azure Container Instance` and you would like to retrieve the logs for it?

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-get-logs), you can use the `az` CLI to request logs of the application container. This is essentially a stdout redirect of your container, which should include everything you need.

Does this help?